# how to generate test reports for junit test with play 2 framefork?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I run some integration tests. This tests are "integration" so i should run fake application with h2 database for it and do some other work that take some time. I cant do it for every test class cause it takes much time. I use junit Suite for group my tests with code like this:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({Step1Test.class, Step2Test.class})
public class IntegrationTests {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        // Start fake app, prepare fixtures etc...
        System.out.println("setUp");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        // stop fake app
        System.out.println("tearDown");
    }
}
```

and run test from console:

```
play "test-only suits.*"
```

But target/test-reports are empty - sbt do not create any report about this test.
When i run every single test class directly:

```
play "test-only steps.*"
```

test reports are created.

Source available at https://github.com/zadonskiyd/play2JunitTestSuiteProblem

What should i do to create xml reports for tests that runs from suite ?